# HighChart Renders Blank with Small Data Set

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Below is the chart I am trying to create , I took it straight from the examples  and replaced the x-axis data and added in my own series data. In the console it prints out both of the arrays I used like this:

> Reports:28,16,1,4,6,4,5,31,59,43,31,56,4 
>   HOURSSS:0,1,2,4,6,7,9,11,12,13,14,15,16

and for some reason the chart just ends up looking like the pic below. I have been stumped on this for hours. Any idea whats going on?

```
var activityTotalDayByHour =  <?php echo json_encode($activityTotalDayByHour); ?>;
console.log("ACTIVITY:"+activityTotalDayByHour);
var Reports = [];
var Hours =[]
for (var i = 0; i < activityTotalDayByHour.length; i++) {
    Reports.push(activityTotalDayByHour[i]['Records']);
    Hours.push(activityTotalDayByHour[i]['Hour']);
}
$(function () {
        $('#highChartDiv').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'area'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'US and USSR nuclear stockpiles'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: <a href="http://thebulletin.metapress.com/content/c4120650912x74k7/fulltext.pdf">' +
                    'thebulletin.metapress.com</a>'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: Hours
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name} produced <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>warheads in {point.x}'
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'USA',
                data:Reports
            }]
        });
    });
      </script>
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @Jeromy French I have discovered it has to be something funky going on w. my data source. When I plug in the exact same data into static arrays it works just fine, but when I use the arrays created via my loops it does not work. Even more weird is that if I create 2 versions of my data ( one formed through looping through the dynamic data and one formed by plugging in the exact same static data into arrays it console.log's out identical like this :

```
---Looped Versions----
Reports:28,16,1,4,6,4,5,31,59,43,31,56,10
HOURSSS:0,1,2,4,6,7,9,11,12,13,14,15,16
--Static Versions---
REPORTS_B:28,16,1,4,6,4,5,31,59,43,31,56,4
HOURS_B:0,1,2,4,6,7,9,11,12,13,14,15,16

var activityTotalDayByHour =  <?php echo json_encode($activityTotalDayByHour); ?>;
console.log("ACTIVITY:"+activityTotalDayByHour);
var Reports = [];
var Hours =[]
for (var i = 0; i < activityTotalDayByHour.length; i++) {
    Reports.push(activityTotalDayByHour[i]['Records']);
    Hours.push(activityTotalDayByHour[i]['Hour']);
}


var USA=[null, null, null, null, null, 6, 11, 32, 110, 235, 369, 640,
1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618, 6444, 9822, 15468, 20434, 24126,
27387, 29459, 31056, 31982];


console.log("Reports:"+Reports);
console.log("HOURSSS:"+Hours);

var Reports_b=[28,16,1,4,6,4,5,31,59,43,31,56,4],
    Hours_b=[0,1,2,4,6,7,9,11,12,13,14,15,16];

    console.log("REPORTS_B:"+Reports_b);
    console.log("HOURS_B:"+Hours_b);
```

Comment: Is "HOURSSS" (in "HOURSSS:0,1,2,4,6,7,9,11,12,13,14,15,16") a typo?

Comment: Its just a console log aka  console.log("HOURSSSS:+Hours);

Comment: Pretty sure Highcharts wants series values in arrays: `var Hours=[28,16,1,4,6,4,5,31,59,43,31,56,4]` . It doesn't seem you are using that notation (based on your log output). If you are, can you post a JSFiddle?

Comment: I have my data in arrays, i probably should of added my array code in my original post. Ive edited my post and added in the arrays being formed as well as the console logs exactly as it is in my project script tag to script tag aka:


var activityTotalDayByHour =  <?php echo json_encode($activityTotalDayByHour); ?>;
console.log("ACTIVITY:"+activityTotalDayByHour);
var Reports = [];
var Hours =[]
for (var i = 0; i < activityTotalDayByHour.length; i++) {
    Reports.push(activityTotalDayByHour[i]['Records']);
    Hours.push(activityTotalDayByHour[i]['Hour']);
}

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/cfreedhh/1/ . Does your JS console show any errors?

Comment: One difference: I don't encapsulate my `highcharts()` call within a `function()`. Why are you...and when/how do you *call* that function?

Comment: Im very new to highcarts, i literally just copied a example and switched the data source. your version works for me as well so that means it has to be my data source. How could it be possible that my data source could print perfectly in the log , but not work for the chart?

Comment: I still think your series values might be the problem--you can see on the Fiddle that I hard-code mine to the values you provide. What does `console.log( Hours );` yield? `console.log( Reports );`?

Comment: See my edit I just mentioned you in on my original post , its a odd problem , but I think the answer below might be on to something.

Comment: The issue has been solved , but thank you for your time and working through this with me!

Comment: PS--whoischuckkelly.com seems to be "down"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going out on a bit of a limb here, but i believe your issue is down to the fact that your `Reports` array is made up of strings (instead of numbers) - i've had the same issue from time to time.

Either modify the data `Reports` is pulling data from, or alternatively do it as you push in to `Reports`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < activityTotalDayByHour.length; i++) {
    Reports.push(parseInt(activityTotalDayByHour[i]['Records'], 10));
    Hours.push(activityTotalDayByHour[i]['Hour']);
}
```

Comment: All hail the king , You are a genius my friend.....so obvious in retrospect, I think all these open source libraries are making all of us a bit entitled and lazy .For some reason I just expected the library to be smart enough to convert strings to ints and ect. Thank you.

Comment: @ChuckKelly Yeah, that's the same pitfall that I stumble in to as well. Happy that it was the issue and it's sorted for you.